# How to give dots or point or period before the number of equation

Tags: equations, numbering

Hi I want to ask how to give period before the number of equation.

For Example

```
A = B + C            ...(1)
```

Comment: Like this: `\begin{equation}A=B+C \dots \end{equation}`? Or if you prefer, `A=B+C+ \cdots`

Comment: After formating your post I see that you wrote dots very near the equation number. Do you really want that or dots should be after `C`? What is the meaning of dots near equation number?

Comment: Thank you all @Sigur for your help. I don't know what's the name is. thank you again.

Comment: thankyou @JouleV. I just googling and don't get it until you gave this.. thanks again